# Selenium Test run opens up a new private window which I didn't implement in my test

Tags: selenium, firefox, browser

I wrote a test script to my web site using Selenium. My test was perfect and ran without any errors. But, because of some malware of my browser I re-installed my browser. After that when I run my test It opens a new private window and closes after sometime.

This error shows up in the console.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1459395552778   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}
1459395552778   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} in app-global
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\Manuli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous2544125435660511785webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1459395548931,"mt":1459395548792}},"app-system-defaults":{"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"0.1","st":1458092953000}},"app-global":{"{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi","e":true,"v":"8.0.0.9103","st":1452090606000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"45.0.1","st":1458092953000}}}
1459395552780   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1459395552785   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1459395552786   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1459395552795   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 0.1
1459395552806   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2544125435660511785webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1459395552811   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1459395552811   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1459395552812   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1459395552819   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1459395552820   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1459395552822   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1459395552858   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1459395552858   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1459395552862   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1459395552862   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1459395553007   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1459395553007   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1459395553008   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1459395553083   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1459395553083   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1459395553084   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at userlogin.login(userlogin.java:23)
    at ayubomain.main(ayubomain.java:15)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1459395552778   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}
1459395552778   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} in app-global
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\Manuli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous2544125435660511785webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1459395548931,"mt":1459395548792}},"app-system-defaults":{"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"0.1","st":1458092953000}},"app-global":{"{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi","e":true,"v":"8.0.0.9103","st":1452090606000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"45.0.1","st":1458092953000}}}
1459395552780   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1459395552785   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1459395552786   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1459395552795   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 0.1
1459395552806   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2544125435660511785webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1459395552811   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1459395552811   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1459395552812   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1459395552819   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1459395552820   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1459395552822   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1459395552858   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1459395552858   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1459395552862   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1459395552862   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1459395553007   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1459395553007   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1459395553008   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1459395553083   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1459395553083   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1459395553084   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider

Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'ET_LAHIRU', ip: '192.168.1.2', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at userlogin.login(userlogin.java:23)
    at ayubomain.main(ayubomain.java:15)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1459395552778   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}
1459395552778   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} in app-global
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1459395552779   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\Manuli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous2544125435660511785webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1459395548931,"mt":1459395548792}},"app-system-defaults":{"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"0.1","st":1458092953000}},"app-global":{"{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi","e":true,"v":"8.0.0.9103","st":1452090606000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"45.0.1","st":1458092953000}}}
1459395552780   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1459395552785   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1459395552786   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1459395552795   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 0.1
1459395552806   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2544125435660511785webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1459395552811   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1459395552811   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1459395552812   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1459395552819   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1459395552820   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1459395552822   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1459395552857   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1459395552858   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1459395552858   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1459395552861   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1459395552862   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1459395552862   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1459395553007   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1459395553007   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1459395553008   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1459395553083   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1459395553083   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1459395553084   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
```

This is the window that opens.

[image]

Can anyone tell me wats going on?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show your code as well?  Also check your version of Selenium!  The newer Firefox updates made some versions of Selenium incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because of new issue in latest browser of firefox.

Update your selenium jars. The new version of firefox(Or different browser) is not supporting old jars of selenium.

Download both Selenium Server (formerly the Selenium RC Server) Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings

Replace them with old jars you are using. Update your mozilla also so you can get the updated results

source :- `http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/`

To overcome from this issue you also need to `setPreference` as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false` to firefox Profile and then pass it to driver object

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
```

Below code is working fine for me.

```
    static WebDriver driver=null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

Hope it will help you :)